# Grafana alert CloudWatch datassource: tsdb.HandleRequest()

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm in the process of setting up alerts in Grafana with metrics coming from a CloudWatch data source.

I am monitoring unhealthy hosts in a network load balancer. The alert triggers fine when the unhealthy host count rises, however I see the following error in the email and logs:

`tsdb.HandleRequest() error Invalid time range: Start time must be before end time`

Here is a screenshot of the alert setup:
[image: alert setup[1]]

I've tried tweaking the various intervals with no change in the error. It has to be now-1m in the query as NLB only reports metrics once a minute.

Any ideas what could be wrong?